# PHP preg_replace string path given

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have issue with preg_replace function in PHP. I cant figure out a pattern and a replacement.

I have this two strings and some code:

```
    $dirname1 = 'hdadas/dasdad/dasd/period_1min';
    $dirname2 = 'hdadas/dasdad/dasd/period_1min/abcdrfg.php';

    $pieces1 = explode('/', $dirname1);
    $pieces2 = explode('/', $dirname2);

    $dirname1 = end($pieces1);  // output will be period_1min
    $dirname2 = end($pieces2); // output will be abcdrfg.php

    $output = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $dirname1); // or (..,..,$dirname2

    echo $output; // i need 1min(without period_) or abcdrfg (without .php)
```

**UPD:**

```
   function Cat($dirname)
   {
      $name = explode('/', $dirname);

      $pattern = ???;
      $replacement = ???;

      return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $dirname1);
    }

    print(Cat('hdadas/dasdad/dasd/period_1min'))); // output need 1min only
    print(Cat('hdadas/dasdad/dasd/period_1min/abcdrfg.php'))); // output  need abcdrfg only
```

Comment: 1. The first 8 lines is the same as: `$dirname1 = basename($dirname1);` 2. Which pattern does this follow when you want `period_` for the first and `abcdrfg` for the second ?

Comment: i cant figure out what to write in $pattern and $replacement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this regex `/^.+_|\.[^.]+$/`:

```
$dirname1 = 'hdadas/dasdad/dasd/period_1min';
$dirname2 = 'hdadas/dasdad/dasd/period_1min/abcdrfg.php';

$pieces1 = explode('/', $dirname1);
$pieces2 = explode('/', $dirname2);

$dirname1 = end($pieces1);  // output will be period_1min
$dirname2 = end($pieces2); // output will be abcdrfg.php

$output = preg_replace('/^.+_|\.[^.]+$/', '', $dirname1); // or (..,..,$dirname2
echo $output,"\n"; // i need 1min(without period_) or abcdrfg (without .php)

$output = preg_replace('/^.+_|\.[^.]+$/', '', $dirname2); // or (..,..,$dirname2
echo $output,"\n"; // i need 1min(without period_) or abcdrfg (without .php)
```

**Output:**

```
1min
abcdrfg
```

Comment: Thank you, but it outputs abcdrfg.php (with .php) on version 5.3.3

Comment: @Undertaker: Sorry, typo I forget the `+` quantifier in the second example. See my edit, it works now.

Comment: How the regex look like if it will be period_week_sunday?

Comment: @Undertaker: what do you want to keep?

Comment: I want to keep week_sunday

Comment: No, this /^.+_|\.[^.]+$/ regex for "period_weekly_sunday" ouput only "sunday"

Comment: @Yes, you're right, change the the regex to: `^[^_]+_|\.[^.]+$`

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

(Here I use [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to get only the last part of the path, then I use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to get the last part without the extension. After this I just use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace everything before the underscore with an empty string)

```
<?php

    $dirname1 = "hdadas/dasdad/dasd/period_1min";
    $dirname2 = "hdadas/dasdad/dasd/period_1min/abcdrfg.php";

    $dirname1 = pathinfo(basename($dirname1))["filename"];
    $dirname2 = pathinfo(basename($dirname2))["filename"];

    echo $output = preg_replace("/(.*)_/", "", $dirname1); 


?>
```

output:

```
1min
abcdrfg
```

Comment: @Undertaker `echo phpversion();` = ? <5.4 ?

Comment: Yes 5.3.3 that why :)

Comment: @Undertaker Maybe you want to upgrade your php version, we live in 2015, so you can use array dereferencing

Comment: I cant project run on < 5.4

Comment: @Undertaker Then you can change these lines from: `$dirname1 = pathinfo(basename($dirname1))["filename"];` to this: `$dirname1 = pathinfo(basename($dirname1)); $dirname1 = $dirname1["filename"]`

Comment: I agree your implementation are better in highest version in php, because it is smaller and effective.